# Java append attribute and value to existing XML

Tags: java, xml, tomcat

I need to update an server.xml for Apache tomcat dynamically and add a new attribute and value..  This xml document has many elements with attributes with the same name.  For Example multiple connector elements with different attribute values.

```
<Connector protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol"
    port="${tomcat.http.port}" 
    connectionTimeout="${tomcat.connection.timeout}"
    maxHttpHeaderSize="20480"
    socket.soKeepAlive="true" 
/>

<Connector protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol"
    port="${tomcat.basic.https.port}"
    socket.soKeepAlive="true"
    SSLEnabled="true"
    socket.appReadBufSize="17408"
    scheme="https"
    secure="true"
   />
```

I need to add a new attribute where connector in the element where the port value is ${tomcat.basic.https.port}.

This is what I got so far for finding the correct element.

```
    DocumentBuilderFactory docFactory = buildDocFact();
    DocumentBuilder docBuilder = null;
    Document doc = null;

    File file = new File(filePath);
    docBuilder = docFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
    doc = docBuilder.parse(file);
    doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();

    XPath xpath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
    NodeList nodes =
                (NodeList) xpath.evaluate("//*[contains(@port, 
   '${tomcat.basic.https.port}')]", doc,
                        XPathConstants.NODESET);

        for (int idx = 0; idx < nodes.getLength(); idx++)
        {
            Node value = 
            nodes.item(idx).getAttributes().getNamedItem("port");
            String val = value.getNodeValue();
            logger.info(val);
        }
```

So the logger.info prints out the correct value so I know I am in the right element.

The question is how do i add append attribute and value to the end of this element?

There doesn't seem to be a create attribute function.

Once we can set the attrib and value, then I can easy save the results to a new xml doc.

```
    Transformer xformer = TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer();
    xformer.transform(new DOMSource(doc), new StreamResult(new File(outputFile)));
```

Any ideas how I can append a new attribute and value?

I hope that made sense :)

Answer (score 1):

You can try `((Element)node).setAttribute("attributeName", "value");`